# Connect socket.io using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm able to make socket.io work perfectly using node.js but I couldn't pass a variable (user_id) as I connect socket.io not within any request.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

    var server = require("http").Server(express);  
    var io = require("socket.io")(server);
    server.listen(3001);
    io.on('connection', function(client) {
      client.on('order_'+userId, function(data) { // how to get user_id here? I can't put this within any endpoint
          io.emit('order_'+user_id,data);
      });
    });

    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        //I can get my userId here, I'm using passport session

        console.log(res.user.id)
    })
```

Need help from someone who has experience with socket.io and node.js.

Comment: do you want to send and recieve the user_id using socket or otherwise ? your question is not really clear .

Comment: @damitj07 not, I make the end point unique using user_id.

Comment: @damitj07 like i have 3 client, they will listen to my order_123, order_345, order_something_else..

Comment: Marked this a duplicate of your other question which has an answer for getting user data from the socket.io connection event.  In the future, you should edit your prior question to clarify rather than write a new question.  You can use the "edit" link at any time to edit any of your existing questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you better use some authentication method (sending user id as a parameter isn't really secured, you should send some kind of token that you can verify, [JWT](https://jwt.io/) will be a good choice).

any way, you can always send the order event, and pass the user id parameter in the data that passed with the event:

Server:

```
  client.on('order', function(data) { 
      io.emit('order_' + data.user_id);
  });
```

Client:

```
  socket.emit('order', {user_id:1});
```